# Can I remove number from parentheses to some power that contains also infinity if it doesnt have impact on calculating lim?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

I have $\displaystyle\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(3 n-1)^2(n+3)^3}{(n+7)^4(n-5)^2}$ and thats how I solve this:

$\displaystyle\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(3 n-1)^2(n+3)^3}{(n+7)^4(n-5)^2}=\left[\frac{\infty}{\infty}\right]=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{9n^2\cdot n^3}{n^4 \cdot n^2}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{9n^5}{n^6}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}9\cdot \frac{1}{n}=9\cdot 0=0$

I removed the numbers from the brackets that in my opinion have no effect due to the adjacent infinity and I left the brackets with powers for what was left and then I calculated in an obvious way. Is it possible? In theory, the result is correct.

Comment: The punchline is that it is valid and yields correct results, but is often seen as "improper" or "handwavy."  If you need to justify yourself to someone else, it is best to know how to go about it the long way... but for quick and dirty calculations, yes this is exactly what most of us do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $n$ is tending to $\infty$, and the expressions are just polynomials, we only care about the leading terms (i.e. the highest powers) in each polynomial, so the equalities you have  written are all correct, but sometimes it is not as straightforward. For example, it would be wrong to say:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{n}+1)^2}\right)=\lim_{n\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{n})^2}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n^2)=\infty
\end{align*}

Comment: I think I wouldnt do this in your example cuz $\frac{1}{n}$ would be going to $0$, not infinity so $1$ have impact imo. denominator woulch change to $1$ because $(0+1)^2=1^2=1$ and $\frac{1}{1}=1$ so result is $1$

Comment: My point is that it is safer to work by some rules for how you are allowed to manipulate expressions like these. Your intuition appears to be working well at the moment, but often we can run into unintuitive maths, where not knowing the 'rules' can result in us getting the wrong answer

Comment: I know what you mean, and I agree that these simplifications sometimes fail.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that your calculation has an error, which by sheer luck was cancelled out. Here's what you wrote:
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(3 n-1)^2(n+3)^3}{(n+7)^4(n-5)^2}=\left[\frac{\infty}{\infty}\right]=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{3n^2\cdot n^3}{n^4 \cdot n^2}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{3n^5}{n^6} = \cdots = 0
$$
but here's what you *should* have written:
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(3 n-1)^2(n+3)^3}{(n+7)^4(n-5)^2}=\left[\frac{\infty}{\infty}\right]=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{(3n)^2\cdot n^3}{n^4 \cdot n^2}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{9n^5}{n^6} = \cdots = 0
$$
The reason this ended up not mattering is that $5 < 6$.

However, with just a tiny change in one of the exponents you would have gotten the wrong answer.

For example, if that $4$ exponent in the denominator were changed to a $3$ then your method would give the answer:
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(3 n-1)^2(n+3)^3}{(n+7)^3(n-5)^2}=\left[\frac{\infty}{\infty}\right]=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{3n^2\cdot n^3}{n^3 \cdot n^2}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{3n^5}{n^5} = \cdots = 3
$$
whereas the correct answer should be
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(3 n-1)^2(n+3)^3}{(n+7)^3(n-5)^2}=\left[\frac{\infty}{\infty}\right]=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{(3n)^2\cdot n^3}{n^3 \cdot n^2}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{9n^5}{n^5} = \cdots = 9
$$

Comment: Gosh you are correct, stupid mistake. Thank